# In pandas, convert float64 (with NaN values) to strings (with no decimals showing)

Tags: python, pandas

We are trying to go **from**

```
zed = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [33.0, 67.0, np.nan]})
```

**to**

```
pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': ['33', '67', '']})
```

We've tried `zed['a'].astype(np.int).astype(str)` however this throws the error `Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` because of the NaN value. Is it possible to go from floats to strings with no decimals, and with NaN values replaced by empty strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is use `Int64` for [integer NaN](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html)s and then set empty string:

```
zed['a'] = zed['a'].astype('Int64').astype(str).replace('<NA>','')
print (zed)
    a
0  33
1  67
2
```

Or for old pandas version is possible this alternative:

```
zed['a'] = zed['a'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).mask(zed['a'].isna(),'')
```

---

If need missing values insted empty strings:

```
zed['a'] = zed['a'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).mask(zed['a'].isna())
print (zed)
     a
0   33
1   67
2  NaN
```

Or:

```
zed.loc[zed['a'].notna(), 'a'] = zed['a'].astype('Int64').astype(str)
zed['a'] = zed['a'].astype('Int64').astype(str).replace('<NA>', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the trimming of the decimal at the string level:

```
zed['b'] = zed['a'].fillna('').astype(str).str.replace(r'\..*', '', regex=True)
```

or:

```
zed['b'] = zed['a'].fillna('').astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]
```

or:

```
zed['b'] = zed['a'].map('{:.0f}'.format).replace('nan', '')
```

output:

```
      a   b
0  33.0  33
1  67.0  67
2   NaN
```